# Результат из JSON

Tags: ios, json, вконтакте, swift

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь работать с VK API. Мне нужно проверить, поставил ли пользователь лайк тому или иному посту на стене. Сделал вот такую процедуру для этой цели, но всегда возвращается 0. Что не так? :(

```
func checkLike(postID: Int) -> Int
{
    var liked: Int = Int()
    if VKSdk.accessToken() != nil {
        let request: VKRequest = VKRequest(method: "likes.isLiked", andParameters: ["type":"post", "owner_id":"\(publics.palnom6[1])", "item_id":"\(postID)"])
        request.executeWithResultBlock(
            {
                (response) -> Void in
                let result = response.json as! Dictionary <String, AnyObject>
                liked = result["liked"]! as! Int

            }, errorBlock: {
                (error) -> Void in print("Error checking whether post is liked or not")
        })
    }
    return liked
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для вызова этого метода Ваше приложение должно иметь права: `wall`.

`liked = result["liked"]! as! Int` , судя по документации https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList нужно заменить на
`liked = result["count"]! as! Int`